# Fatal error: Class 'CI_Model' not found on production server, works locally

Tags: codeigniter, fatal-error

We're building a web application with CodeIgniter 2.1.4. It's in the crawling stages. Right now, it only has a basic logging and registering system.

What we've so far functions as expected locally, but when we try it online, we get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'CI_Model' not found in /home4/csurmeli/public_html/other/ems/system/core/Common.php on line 174
```

It doesn't make any sense since we haven't changed any of the core files. And our online server is well established.

Any suggestions?

**The controller calling login:**

```
    function login(){

        if($this->session->userdata('userid') !== false){
            redirect(base_url()."index.php/users/success");
        }

        $data['error'] = 0;
        if($_POST){
            $this->load->model('user');
            $username = $this->input->post('username',true);
            $password = $this->input->post('password',true);
            $user = $this->user->login($username,$password);

            if(!$user){
                $data['error']=1;
                redirect(base_url()."index.php/users/error");
            }else{
                $this->session->set_userdata('userid',$user['userid']);
                $this->session->set_userdata('privilege',$user['privilege']);
                redirect(base_url()."index.php/users/success");
            }   
        }

        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('login',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

**Model:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    Class User Extends CI_Model{

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
        }       
        function create_user($data){
            if($data['is_sent']){
            $query = array("username" => $data['username'],
                            "password" => $data['password'],
                            "email" => $data['email']
                        );
            $this->db->insert('users',$query);
            }
        }

        function login($username,$password){
            $where =  array(
                'username'=>$username,
                'password'=>$password
                );

            $this->db->select()->from('users')->where($where);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->first_row('array');
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal Error: Class 'CI\_Model' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503783/fatal-error-class-ci-model-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

if it works locally - its probably just an issue on the main index.php page

in index.php find the banners: SYSTEM FOLDER NAME and APPLICATION FOLDER NAME 
then double check that the file path and the folder names are correct for your server.

Comment: I checked them. All seems fine. Any other suggestions?

Comment: in your controller you might be calling a method from a model, but you have not loaded the model first. Best is to get something simple working first - like the welcome page - that doesn't require any models or libraries etc.