# codeigniter error when i extends CI_Model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am very new to codeigniter and MVC when I tried to extend CI_Model, I have a Fatal error.
I am doing it like in the examples can you point were I am wrong:

```
    class Site extends CI_Controller {

        public function index(){
            echo "hi internet <br>";
            $this->hello();
            $this->addStuff();
        }

        public function hello(){
            echo " H E L L O <br>";
        }

        public function addStuff(){
            echo "math <br>";
            $this->load->model("math");
            echo $this->Math->add(3,8);
        }
    } 
    class Math extends CI_Model {

        public function add($num1,$num2){
            return $num1+$num2;
        }

        public function sub($num1,$num2){
            return $num1+$num2;
        }

    }
```

My error is:

```
Fatal error: Class 'application\models\CI_Model' not found 
in C:\projects \CodeIgniter\application\models\Math.php on line 12 line 12 is class
Math extends CI_Model line
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal Error: Class 'CI\_Model' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503783/fatal-error-class-ci-model-not-found)

Comment: i wont to extend a model

Comment: class Math extends CI_Model

Comment: Ok, and file is in application/models folder, and name of file is math.php? Maybe reserved word is in question... not sure

Comment: Both of your Controller and Model are in the same file ? and please provide the file names along with the path.

Comment: Are you using latest version of CI, earlier it was only Model and now CI_Model

Comment: @Nish, he is probably using the latest version, because the controller is working fine. There error pops up when he tries to load the model.

Comment: Ok thanks found it it was the   namespace application\models;

Answer (score 0):

in application/controllers-
create site.php file-

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {

        public function index(){
            echo "hi internet <br>";
            $this->hello();
            $this->addStuff();
        }

        public function hello(){
            echo " H E L L O <br>";
        }

        public function addStuff(){
            echo "math <br>";
            $this->load->model("math");
            echo $this->Math->add(3,8);
        }
    }
```

in application/models
create math.php file

```
class Math extends CI_Model {

        public function add($num1,$num2){
            return $num1+$num2;
        }

        public function sub($num1,$num2){
            return $num1+$num2;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to make site.php controller and use like that

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller 
{
}
```

and model you can make site_model.php and use like that

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site_Model extends CI_Model
{
}
```